# Retrieve Google Auth-token without explicitly choosing account on device

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-authentication

I am following [this article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) from Android's official documentation to identify the device/user making calls to my backend server.

The article is old, but has been revised recently. `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(email, scope)` is deprecated now, and I replaced that part with the newer API:

```
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
                .build()
```

The linked article has a section called "Magic Happens", which says:

> Normally, when you ask for an OAuth token, the person using the device
>   sees a challenge, asking them if it’s OK to use their identity to get
>   at some resource or other. But in this case, the system looks at the
>   server-side Client ID in your scope argument, notices that it’s in the
>   same project as your Android app, and gives you the token without
>   pestering the user; they’ve already agreed to a relationship with you,
>   the developer who controls that project.

Therefore, I was expecting that `requestIdToken()` method will **NEVER** prompt the user with any permission dialog, but I see the account selection dialog being shown to the user. It ***can be made a one time prompt*** by using `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount()`, but I was hoping to have no prompt at all. My app does not have a Google Sign-In option, and asking them to share their Google account may not seem sensible to them.

Did I misunderstand the article? Or is it outdated?